# How do I find out when the last party fires Phaser.arrive()?

Tags: java, concurrency, phaser

Given:

```
Executor executor = ...;
Phaser phaser = new Phaser(n);
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
  Runnable task = new Runnable()
  {
    public void run()
    {
      phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
      if (lastTask)
        doSomething(this);
    }
  }

  // run tasks using a thread-pool (order is not guaranteed)
  executor.submit(task);
}
```

I'd like to find out if I'm the last task in order to fire `doSomething()` that depends upon the task's internal state. I found [Phaser.onAdvance(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html#onAdvance%28int,%20int%29) but it's not clear how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a very elegant way of solving this but the use of ThreadLocal and the onAdvance can help.

```
    final ThreadLocal<Boolean> isLast = new ThreadLocal<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean initialValue() {
            return false;
        }
    };
    final Phaser p = new Phaser(9) {
        public boolean onAdvance(int phase, int registeredParties) {
            isLast.set(true);
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Then

```
  public void run()
    {
      phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
      if (isLast.get())
        doSomething(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to know *a priori* how many tasks you have, just use a separate `AtomicInteger`.

```
int n = 5;
ExecutorService executor = ...
final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger (n);
final Phaser phaser = new Phaser (n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        public void run () {
            phaser.arriveAndDeregister ();
            if (count.decrementAndGet () == 0) {
                doSomething (this);
            }
        }
    };

    // run tasks using a thread-pool (order is not guaranteed)
    executor.submit (task);
}
```

Or, if you need to call `doSomething` before dormant parties are notified, just override `onAdvance` and do it from there.

```
final Phaser phaser = new Phaser (n) {
    protected boolean onAdvance(int phase, int registeredParties) {
        doSomething(this);

        return super.onAdvance(phase, registeredParties);
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think your code should check `if (registeredParties == 0)` because `onAdvance()` is guaranteed to only get invoked after all parties have arrived. Whether there are 0 parties waiting or more, the event should fire.